# windows command line output pipe or redirection in real time and publish to mqtt broker

Tags: windows, command-line, pipe, io-redirection, mqtt

Is it possible to **read** a continuously running windows command output and publish to **mqtt** broker **continuously** under **windows7/8/2012** OS?

(No 3rd party software, I am using windows command prompt, not powershell)

windows command:

```
ping -t www.google.com
```

mqtt publish

```
mosquitto_pub -h iot.eclipse.org -t MyTopic/pingstatus -m "Ping Console Output Goes Here"
```

My idea format (not exist as year 2015...)

```
ping -t www.google.com | assign output to %%variable | mosquitto_pub -h iot.eclipse.org -t MyTopic/pingstatus -m %%variable
```

DO NOT give me `for loop` solution, it will publish to the broker only after the 1st command finished the process.

I want `command_1.exe | command_2.exe` run **continuously / in real time**.

That means the `command_1` is still running while `command_2` publish mqtt messages one by one.

Comment: Unfortunately, `mosquitto_pub -l` read stdin only works in Linux, not windows. so I cannot `cmd1.exe | mosquitto -l`.

Comment: Are you sure this would stream the incoming lines continuously to the mqtt  destination ? What happens if the ping statement runs for lets say 10 minutes ? I doubt this will work the way you want it to.

Comment: I can answer my own question ;-) The docs say that (as you say only on Linux) the -l switch will: Send messages read from stdin, splitting separate lines into separate messages. Note that blank lines won't be sent.

Comment: `mosquitto_pub -l` actually does work on Windows btw

Answer (score 0):

Why not pipe the ping output to a file (like `ping foo > pingoutput.txt`) and have that file transferred by using `-f pingoutput.txt` ?

Comment: `-f pingoutput.txt`, can be specific? is it real time(ping still running)? thanks

Comment: Sorry, it looks like I did not understand your need in the beginning. What is your exakt goal ? Do you want a huge document be sent to the mqtt destination ? Or do you want the first line to be sent, then the second (overwriting the previously sent first one), then the third (overwriting the previously sent second one) and so on ? I would ping once, publish the result, ping again. But I think this is the for loop solution you exclude.

Comment: I want publish ping results continuously (1,2,3...) to my own mqtt broker. the ping command and mqtt_pub command should be separate entities.

Comment: And what speaks against ping -n 1 and publishing that ? I know you wrote you dont want to loop but what is the practical reason ? And why with a batch and no additional software ? You have to provide mosquitto too, so why bot use or provide something more capable than batches ?

Comment: I have a `continous.exe` gives me some readings based on the previous reading, so I cannot ask the exe to stop and publish to mqtt, I have to let it run continuously. batch comes with windows and I just feel it is straight forward to use it. If you have other suggestions, please let me know. thanks.

Comment: so ping was just an example for a program delivering consecutive output ... I understand. High level languages allow you to read an already open stream (like stdin) continuously. I did something like this in Java (which is my preferred language) and read the output of a command line program line by line in order to process each of them. I am sure you can do this in any other language too (If you have a preferred one). And this has the additional advantage that you could use a "real" mqtt library and not only use the command line of mosquitto_pub.